# Ratio of products of line segments

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

The points $A,B,C,D$ are collinear.  The point $P$ sits off the line, and  $\angle{APB}=\angle{CPD}=\theta.$

I'd like to show that if the points $P,A,D$ are fixed, the ratio $\dfrac{AB\cdot AC}{DC\cdot DB}$ is independent of $\theta$.

I noticed that this ratio is equal to $(PA/PD)^2$, so it would suffice to show that these quantities are the same.

I'd be especially interested in knowing whether this result is well known or has a name.   This problem came up when I was investigating a special case of [Carnot's Theorem for Conics](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/CarnotForConics.shtml).

Comment: This property is connected to **isogonal conjugation** within a triangle $ABC$ with sidelengths $a,b,c$. In particular the fact that if $A$ has barycentric coordinates $(x,y,z)$, its isogonal conjugate $A^*$ has barycentric coordinates $(a^2/x,b^2/y,c^2/z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known result known as [Steiner's ratio theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SteinersTheorem.shtml). The proof uses essentially just the law of sines, but I'll reproduce it here.

**Lemma:** (sometimes known as the ratio theorem). For $\triangle ABC$ with $D$ on $BC$, we have
$$\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{AB}{AC}\frac{\sin(\angle BAD)}{\sin(\angle DAC)}.$$
Proof of lemma: By law of sines,
\begin{align*}
\frac{BD}{DC}&=\frac{BD}{AB}\frac{AC}{DC}\frac{AB}{AC}\\
&=\frac{\sin(\angle BAD)}{\sin(\angle BDA)}\frac{\sin(\angle ADC)}{\sin(\angle DAC)}\frac{AB}{AC}\\
&=\frac{AB}{AC}\frac{\sin(\angle BAD)}{\sin(\angle DAC)}
\end{align*}
as claimed.

Then using the lemma, we have
$$\frac{AB}{BD}\frac{AC}{CD}=\left(\frac{PA}{PD}\right)^2\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\angle APD-\theta)}\frac{\sin(\angle APD-\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\left(\frac{PA}{PD}\right)^2.$$

Comment: [+1] Thanks! Nothing like a well known theorem one didn’t know existed.